# Which Cypher query should I use to add label using spring neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying this query:

@Query(value = "match (n) where id(n)={id} set n:{label}")
    public void setNodeLabel(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("label") String label);

but getting error :

org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 34)
"match (n) where id(n)={id} set n:{label}"

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels can't be passed as parameters, you have to specify them as part of your textual query.
That's a limitation of Cypher, not SDN

Just use:

```
template.query("match (n) where id(n)={id} set n:"+label,map("id",id));
```

Comment: ok. thank you. I have one request to make. You created labels annotation. Can you create label annotation to add one label to node.